# cancelListener vs keyListener

Tags: android, dialog, keylistener

I want dismissDialog(ID) to be called whenever dialog is gone (disapears, get closed , ...), so it may happen when user press BACK button or any other scenario that may close the dialog.

which one is better approach? to call onCancelListener on dialog? or call OnKeyListener and assign `if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
// do smth`

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#onBackPressed%28%29), to do cleanup or whatever you want to do in dismissdialog()

Answer (score 0):

if you do not ant to allow to dialog disappear,when back button pressed.it can be done by setting dialog's property as below:

---

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);//here dialog is object of Dialog class which you want to show
```